DATA_PATH_1 when exporting linked resources
We use spoon to run scripts to migrate new customers from their old system into ours.
Recently, we've added a step that reads from a file and it's causing us an issue when we export it from our development environment to run for our customers.
We use both Spoon 7 and PDI 9.4. Both versions seem to be replacing a file path with DATA_PATH_1. I understand this is to turn a path into a parameter, and allow it to be easily edited after it's been moved to a new location.
Our problem is that we already do this using variables read in during a Set Variables step. So it is turning something like ${path_variable}/sub_folder/filename.csv into ${DATA_PATH_1}/filename.csv. And the value of DATA_PATH_1 is now set to the value of path_variable (as set in our development environment) instead of the parameter, and it's causing to ignore the fact that path_variable is set to a different value for the new run environment.
Is there anyway we can get Spoon/PDI to stop trying to help?
